# Pandas - two columns as index (valid time and row number)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv that looks like this

```
valid,value
2004-07-21 09:00:00,200
2004-07-21 10:00:00,200
2004-07-21 11:00:00,150
```

I **must** set the valid column as index like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['valid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid'])  # convert 'valid' column to pd.datetime objects
df = df.set_index('valid')  # set the 'valid' as index
```

I would still like to be able to access the data by row index too however like this

```
for row_index in range(len(df)):  # I know iterating over a df is not avisable
    print(df.at[row_index])
```

But I get an error. `ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers`

**I for sure have to have the valid column as index. But how can I also print a row given it's index?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change selecting by label:

```
print(df.at[row_index])
```

to selecting by positions with select first column by [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
for row_index in range(len(df)):  # I know iterating over a df is not avisable
    #convert position of value column to 0  
    print(df.iat[row_index, df.columns.get_loc('value')])
    #selecting first column - 0
    #print(df.iat[row_index, 0])
200
200
150
```

Or use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
for row_index in range(len(df)):  # I know iterating over a df is not avisable
    print(df.iloc[row_index])

value    200
Name: 2004-07-21 09:00:00, dtype: int64
value    200
Name: 2004-07-21 10:00:00, dtype: int64
value    150
Name: 2004-07-21 11:00:00, dtype: int64
```

Difference is `iat` is faster, but return intersection index/column value - scalar, but `iloc` is more general, here return all columns to Series - Series name is index values, index values of Series are columns names.

Comment: Any reason to use the `.iat` or `.iloc` method over the other?

Comment: Added to answer to end.

Answer (score 1):

```
for row_index in range(len(df)):  
   print(df.iloc[row_index])
```